# How to implement barcode scanner in reactjs application?

Tags: reactjs, npm, barcode-scanner

I am developing an Order Scan web application, and the challenge I'm facing is that, if barcode matches, where I'm going to receive data in my react.js application. I'll be using a barcode scanner device, so can I use this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-barcode-reader. If so, how to implement it in my react app?

I have searched the web for answers. I couldn't find anything to my specific problem in react.js.

Comment: Are you trying to react  a bar code from your web app or are you trying to display barcodes on your app ?

Comment: React a bar code??

Comment: I am trying to get data in my react app, by using a barcode reader. As barcode reader is an input device, how can i fetch data from that in my react app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A barcode scanner is simply an input device. Just think of it as a keyboard.
You may receive its inputs via any TextInputs component.

If your barcode scanner is programmed to terminate with "\n", then the TextInput will also trigger onSubmit event.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the React Barcode Scanner NPM package. A simple demonstration is on that site. You can use their Barcode Scanner component:

```
<BarcodeReader
onError={handleError}
onScan={handleScan}
/>
```

You can apply that component in where you want the user to perform the scan. You will just need to make a handleScan and handleError function.

Examples:

```
const [scanData, setScanData] = useState()

const handleScan = (data) => {
  setScanData(data)
}

const handleError = (err) => console.error(err)
```

The data will be stored in the scanData variable. Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple example for barcode reading in React, using simple vanilla javascript:

This works using timeframe to detect barcode readings. You can easily change it for endline codes (you won't need the timeout)

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [barcodeRead, setBarcodeRead] = useState("");

  const barcode = {
    timing: 1000,
    data: "",
  };

  const barcodeReaded = () => {
    if (barcode.data.length > 1) {
      setBarcodeRead(barcode.data);
    } else {
      barcode.data = "";
    }
  };

  let timeout = setTimeout(barcodeReaded, 500);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
      console.log(e.key);
      console.log(e.timeStamp);
      if (barcode.data.length === 0 || e.timeStamp - barcode.timing < 200) {
        barcode.data += e.key;
        barcode.timing = e.timeStamp;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(barcodeReaded, 500);
      } else {
        barcode.data = "";
      }
      console.log(barcode);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Readed: {barcodeRead}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```